# creating a series of files duplicates and renaming them

Tags: r

I have a list of climate files in a folder (EDU link: https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/index.php/s/QFpaBDR7q2GbDCN). They are named as follow `p[year][month]_0p5.asc`.

Example:

```
p198001_0p5.asc

p198002_0p5.asc

...

p198012_0p5.asc

p198101_0p5.asc

...

p201012_0p5.asc
```

I wish to create 2000 years of data by repeating in that order these 31 years (1980 to 2010) and renaming them to have a list of files from `p198001_0p5.asc` to `p397912_0p5.asc`

As example, the final folder will include `p201101_0p5.asc` which contains the same data as `p198001_0p5.asc` but will be named `p201101_0p5.asc`.

I have no idea how to do this in R. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update 19-07-2017: @Mako212** suggestion seems to work but I had memory issues (error message # protect(): protection stack overflow). I changed my strategy and created another script based on his kind suggestion to generate 131 years of data from 1880 to 2010. I did this by repeating the series of 31 years (1980-2010). Here is the code in case you'd like to have a look at that strategy too. It works fine:

```
require(purrr)
require(data.table) 
library(raster)

setwd('...')
files <- list.files(pattern= "*.asc")
files
length(files)

fileDF <- files %>% map(raster)

#set the output directory
output_dir <- "..."

#  set month and year counters
startYear <- 2010 
startMonth <- 12
fileNumber <- 1

for (i in fileDF){
  startYear <- 2010 - (fileNumber-1) %/% 12
  for (x in 1:6){
    print(startYear)
    print(startMonth)
    print(fileNumber)
    writeRaster(i, paste(output_dir, sprintf("p%d%s%d_0p5.asc", startYear, ifelse(startMonth<10,0,""), startMonth), sep="/"), format = "ascii")
    startYear <- startYear - 31
    if (startYear < 1880) break #  don't create files before December, 1880
  }
  if (startMonth > 1 ) {
    startMonth <- startMonth - 1
  }
  else{
    startMonth <- 12
  }
  fileNumber <- fileNumber + 1    
}
```

Comment: I think you can get there with a nested `for` loop. You'll need `list.files(pattern = "*.asc")`. Then something along the lines of `for (f in files){ for (x in 1:65){ write.csv(f, sprintf("p%d",x))}}`. It'll take a little more finesse to construct the full file name, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's the general idea:

```
require(purrr)
require(data.table) 
#  after playing with SDMTools::read.asc, data.table::fread seems to
#  be more reliable. That said, if fread() isn't reading your data
#  correctly, you might try using the SDMTools function instead. 
#  I also chose to save everything as .csv, but again, you can try 
#  using the SDMTools read/write.asc functions if you want

files <- list.files(pattern= "*.asc")


fileDF <- files %>% map(fread)

#  set month and year counters

startYear <- 1980 
startMonth <- 1
fileNumber <- 1

for (i in fileDF){


    #  increment startYear by 1 every 13th file   
    startYear <- 1980 + (fileNumber-1) %/% 12

    for (x in 1:65){
        #  added underscore for clarity between year and month
        #  format is p1980_01_0p5.csv
        write.csv(i, sprintf("p%d_%s%d_0p5.csv", startYear, ifelse(startMonth<10,0,""), startMonth))
        startYear <- startYear + 31

        #  don't create files past December, 3979
        if (startYear > 3979) break
    }
    if (startMonth < 12) {
        startMonth <- startMonth +1
    }
    else{
        startMonth <- 1
    }

    fileNumber <- fileNumber + 1    


}
```

The loop counters are set assuming you have exactly 31 years worth of data (12*31 files)

Make sure you write to a new folder (not the one that contains the source data)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have used `fileDF <- files %>% map(raster)` and `writeRaster` in my code. All the 12 months for 1980, 2011, 2042…3964 (31 year increments) are saved properly but then the loop goes back to 1980 month 1 filenumber 13 and thus I have an issue of files overwritting. I have added a sample of 31*12 .asc files (EDU link)

Comment: @Cecile Can you post the code you're running right now? It sounds like there might be a typo somewhere. `fileNumber` should never go down if the loop is running correctly. The loop should end and `fileNumber` should equal 372

Comment: @Cecile in the meantime I'm downloading your sample data to see if I can find any issues

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. My R code:  https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/index.php/s/zLMg1uuNEVBBhWa @Mako212

Comment: @Cecile Try adding `if (fileNumber == 373) break` below `fileNumber <- fileNumber + 1` in the for loop.

Comment: Also check that `length(files)` is 372

Comment: I added the break line and can confirm that `length(files)` is 372. I ran the new script but same issue @Mako212

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149508/discussion-between-mako212-and-cecile).

Comment: @Cecile I updated the code with the fixed increment on year, so it should work now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same issue with the new code. I have tried a few different ways too, but unsuccessfully (I am a novice though).

Comment: @Cecile try it one more time. I just updated the code, and I think I finally got it 100% right

Comment: @Cecile I was looking at this again today, and I thought I'd mention that if these is a repeated process you might want to use Python because it will be a lot faster that reading in each file just to make a copy. I can share some code with you if you're interested, but if it's not a repeated process, it's probably not an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for offering. I don't need the python code for now, but will let you know if I need it in the near future.